# Export ixf in db2

Tags: db2, squirrel-sql

```
EXPORT TO myFile.ixf OF ixf SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE SSN='DATA' AND EMPLOYER_ID=DATA AND CREATED_TS='DATA'
```

I am using this statement to export a couple of rows. for privacy purposes DATA has been inserted where necessary. however the following error is produced. I have followed IBM's guide on export and feel like this should be correct but unsure exactly as to what is wrong. the error log is as follows

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=myFile;EXPORT TO ;JOIN, DRIVER=3.53.70
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
```

Comment: The `export`  command is not a SQL command if I'm not mistaken. You need to run that from the command line, not from a SQL client. See e.g. here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/47822/1822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already remarked, you cannot *directly* run Db2-commands (such as import, export, load ... etc.)  from plain SQL , as you are trying to do via JDBC.

Instead, if your Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, you can either use a stored procedure,  or (for any Db2-server operating system) you can use the command-line.

However, when you use stored-procedure SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD for Db2-LUW, all file-names in stored-procedure parameters are *relative to the Db2-server* (and not your remote jdbc-client, if you are running remotely).
That means after a successful export via stored-procedure, if you really need the exported IXF file to be on your workstation then you must do file-transfer to your workstation using whatever tools you have for that purpose.

For example, this shows an export on Unix to an IXF file in /tmp on the Db2-server:

```
call sysproc.admin_cmd('EXPORT TO /tmp/myFile.ixf OF ixf SELECT * FROM user1.stk1 with ur') ;
```

If you *don't* want to use a stored procedure, you must use the command-line shell (for example on Windows, use db2ntcmd.bat , or on Unix use bash or ksh) and connect to the database in the shell and perform the export. This requires the workstation to have a Db2-client and also that the relevant database and node be first catalogued.

If you specify your Db2-version and the operating-system on which your Db2-server runs, then you will get more details.